# $.getJSON changing object property for no reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

The code I'm working on has a poolGames array full of poolGame objects, each of which have a unique gameid property. This section of code that I'm debugging makes an API call to search for all live games, matching on the gameid property.

Here is the API call:

```
} else if (game.gametime < game.now) {
    console.log(game.gameid);
    var liveAPI = 'pickem/picksheet/liveTest.json';
    $.getJSON(liveAPI, function() {
        type: 'json'
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).done(function(liveData) {
        console.log(game.gameid);
        var liveGames = zipArrays(liveData.Livedata);
        var liveGame = $.grep(liveGames, function(g) { return g.gameid == game.gameid })[0];
        fullDate = new Date (1000 * game.gametime).toString('ddd, MMM dd - ') + 'LIVE - ' + liveGame.qtr + ': ' + liveGame.timeleft;
        $(dateRow).css('background-color', '#f7931e');
        $(dateInfo).css('color', 'black');
        $(dateRow).css('border', '2px solid black');
        $(dateInfo).html(fullDate);
    });
};
```

And here is the JSON of the Test Page that I'm hitting:

```
{
    "Lastupdated": "N/A",
    "Interval": "868709000",
    "Livedata": {
    "COLUMNS": ["GAMEID", "ROADSCORE", "HOMESCORE", "ISFINAL", "HOMELIVE", "ROADLIVE", "TIMELEFT", "QTR", "HOMEBALL", "HOMEHALF", "DOWN", "YARDLINE", "DBDATE", "REDZONE", "LASTUPDATED", "ENDTIME", "GAMETIME", "GAMESTATUS"],
    "DATA": [
        [29911, 0, 0, false, 13, 10, "4:13", "2nd", false, false, "3", 42, "January, 26 2017 14:11:30", false, null, "February, 05 2017 19:15:00", "February, 05 2017 15:30:00", 2]
        ]
    }
}
```

I've included the console logs so that I can include this dev tools readout, which shows that the gameid property is changed during this API call:

[Dev Tools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRewR.png)

The error appears twice because I make the API call twice (I tried removing the second API call, which has the same code, and it didn't change the problem).

Checking the poolGames array after the API call shows that every game within the array has had the gameid property changed to '29915', which is the gameid of the final game.

Any help appreciated. If you need me to include more code let me know, I wasn't sure how much I needed to display here (the file is about 1800 lines total).

Comment: Where's the closing `}` of `"Livedata": {`?

Comment: `type: 'json'` is inside a function, not an object literal.

Comment: As a side note, don't think you need to identify the type with `getJson`. That entire second argument is unnecessary.

Comment: Too many unknowns. We don't know what `zipArrays` does. Create a [mcve] demo that reproduces problem

Comment: The last `});` close it, and `};` close the `else` condition ;-). Btw, unnecessary `;` for the else closure

Comment: "every game within the array has had the gameid property changed to '29915'" - because you have a single object added to the array many times

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added that closure (it was in the code originally, I just forgot to add it here). Igor, the thing is they are all different objects and maintain their other properties (score, gametime etc), the only property that changes is gameid